# R: why providing a list to ellipsis (...) when ellipsis is the last argument does not work?

Tags: r, list, function, ellipsis

I was writing a function which takes advantage of an ellipsis (aka `...`). It lets you specifiy a variable number of additional arguments. I wanted to provide a list with arguments as an additional argument. Below is a reproducible example:

```
f <- function(..., a =1, b = 2){
  l <- list(...)
  print(l)
}
f(list(a = 2))

[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 2
```

The goal of providing additional arguments in a list was to avoid names conflict (the function inside `f` could take an argument named `a` and I wanted to ensure the possibility of providing it).

While changing implementation I noticed that moving ellipsis to the last place in function declaration returns different result (namely, an empty list):

```
g <- function(a =1, b = 2, ...){
  l <- list(...)
  print(l)
}
g(list(a = 2))

list()
```

Being curious, I added printing the default arguments to both functions:

```
f <- function(..., a =1, b = 2){
  l <- list(...)
  print(l)
  print(c(a = a, b = b))
}
g <- function(a =1, b = 2, ...){
  l <- list(...)
  print(l)
  print(c(a = a, b = b))
}

f(list(a = 2)) # results of calling f
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 2


a b 
1 2

g(list(a = 2)) # results of calling g
list()
$a.a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 2
```

So, the first function (`f`) returned the intended output but the second one (`g`) ignored(?) the default argument `a` and somehow modified the list provided thanks to ellipsis.

I would like to understand why both outputs differ from each other. Does it mean that passing a list as an additional argument is possible only when an ellipsis is a first argument in a function call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way arguments work in R is that when you don't name your first argument, R just assumes that goes into the first argument for the function. This is true for the second, third and so forth arguments in the argument list EXCEPT for arguments that come after the `...` - because R doesn't know how many arguments you intend to fit into the `...`, if you want to change the default of whatever comes after it, you have to name it.

So in your case, when you call function `f()`, the object `list(a=2)` goes into the `...`. But in `g()`, that same object goes into a. The only way you can get something into `...` when that is placed at the end of the argument list without including arguements for a and b is to name it something that isn't a or b, e.g. g(c=list(a=1)).

Answer (score 1):

I think the function work as expected if you do not use `list` in the function call: `f(a=2)` and `g(a=2)` would both return `list()` a value of the variable `l`.

Since you pass a list as argument, it is treated as unnamed variable and is assigned to the first formal parameter, which is different for `f` and `g`.

Things would be different, again, if you would do `do.call(f, list(a=2))` and `do.call(g, list(a=2))`. In this case, the value `2` would be assigned to the expected formal parameter `a`.

Comment: I think @kaksat wants the argument NOT to go into a, but rather into `...`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question **Does it mean that passing a list as an additional argument is possible only when an ellipsis is a first argument in a function call?** is No, if you follow correct naming or position when you pass the values during a function call, you won't have issues with incorrect matching of arguments.

It is better practice to name the argument (at least from the second argument) in the function call, so correct name matching takes place with the intended effect.

Failing to mention names during function call will perform positional matching of arguments. This may result in unintended effects, if you fail to send correct values at the right position.

Note the order of the argument names in the printed output. It follows the order of arguments as defined in the function. This correct order will only takes place, if you name the arguments correctly.

When naming of arguments is followed properly, no need to worry about the position of the arguments. You can pass anything to it. It does not necessarily have to be a `list`.

```
f <- function(..., a =1, b = 2){
  mc <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE )
  print(names(mc))
}
g <- function(a =1, b = 2, ...){
  mc <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE )
  print(names(mc))
}

f(c1 = list(z = 2, f = 5), a = 1, b = 2)  # [1] ""   "c1" "a"  "b" 
f(a = 1, c1 = list(z = 2, f = 5), b = 2)  # [1] ""   "c1" "a"  "b"
f(a = 1, c1 = list(z = 2, f = 5), b = 2, c2 = 4) # ""   "c1" "c2" "a"  "b" 
f(c1 = list(z = 2, f = 5), 1, 2, 4) # [1] ""   "c1" ""   ""   ""  


g(c1 = list(z = 2, f = 5), a = 1, b = 2)  # [1] ""   "a"  "b"  "c1"
g(a = 1, c1 = list(z = 2, f = 5), b = 2)  # [1] ""   "a"  "b"  "c1"
g(a = 1, c1 = list(z = 2, f = 5), b = 2, c2 = 4) # [1] ""   "a"  "b"  "c1" "c2"
g(c1 = list(z = 2, f = 5), 1, 2, 4) # [1] ""   "a"  "b"  "c1" ""
```